# How to query a hotel database to return the query for a single room available for three consecutive nights?

Tags: mysql, sql, qsqlquery

I'm trying to find an answer to the following query:
A customer wants a single room for three consecutive nights. Find the first available date in December 2016.

As per the question, this should be the right answer. But I don't know how to  solve it.

```
+-----+------------+
| id  | MIN(i)     |
+-----+------------+
| 201 | 2016-12-11 |
+-----+------------+
```

The link is from [question number 14 here](https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Guest_House_Assessment_Hard).

This is the ER diagram of the database:
[image: ER diagram of the database]

Comment: Hmm.  That's a tough one.  Looks like you're going to have to join between the room and booking tables, then somehow use the booking.boking_date and booking.nights columns to determine the date range of each booking.  If it were just 3 days not booked, it would be much more straightforward, but having to come up with consecutive dates makes things more difficult.

Comment: You should define how single occupancy is defined.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize that I'm a bit rusty with this kind of query and I can't guarantee that I got all of the syntax correct, but I think that something like the following might work:

```
SELECT id, DATE_ADD(b.booking_date, INTERVAL (end_date + 1 DAY) as date
FROM  (
         SELECT r.id, STR_TO_DATE('2016-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d') as start_of_month, b.booking_date as start_date, DATE_ADD(b.booking_date, INTERVAL (nights - 1) DAY) as end_date
         FROM room r
         LEFT JOIN booking b ON r.id = b.room_no
         ORDER BY r.id, b.booking_date
      ) as room_bookings
WHERE DATE_DIFF(room_bookings.start_of_month, room_bookings.start_date) >= 3
OR DATE_DIFF(room_bookings.end_date, (
         SELECT b2.booking_date FROM booking b2
         WHERE b2.room_no = room_bookings.id AND b2.booking_date > room_bookings.start_date
         ORDER BY b2.booking_date LIMIT 1)
      ) >= 3
```

In fact, now that I type that all out, you might be able to tweak the WHERE of the main query so that you don't even need the room_bookings subselect.  Hopefully this helps and isn't too far off the mark.

Answer (score 0):

This seems very hard to do without a calendar table -- because an appropriate room might have no booking at all during the month.  Without any booking, there is no record in the month to start with.

```
select r.id, dte
from rooms r cross join
     (select date('2018-12-01') as dte union all
      select date('2018-12-02') as dte union all
      . . .
      select date('2018-12-32') as dte 
     ) d
where not exists (select 1 from bookings b where b.room_no = r.id and b.booking_date = d.dte) and
      not exists (select 1 from bookings b where b.room_no = r.id and b.booking_date = d.dte + interval 1 day) and
      not exists (select 1 from bookings b where b.room_no = r.id and b.booking_date = d.dte + interval 2 day)
order by d.dte
limit 1;
```

This assumes that `booking_date` is the start of the stay.  You need to provide the logic for a "single room".

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct top 1 alll.i,alll.room_no,
case
when (select count(*) from booking where room_no = alll.room_no and booking_date between dateadd(day,1,alll.i) and dateadd(day,3,alll.i)) > 0  then 'Y'
else 'N'
end as av3
 from
(select c.i,b.room_no,b.booking_date
from calendar c cross join booking b
where month(c.i) = 12 and year(c.i) = 2016 and b.room_type_requested = 'single'
) as alll
join
(
select distinct c.i, b.room_no
from calendar c join booking b
on c.i between b.booking_date and DATEADD(day,b.nights-1,b.booking_date)
where month(c.i) = 12 and year(c.i) = 2016 and b.room_type_requested = 'single'
) as booked
on alll.i = booked.i
and alll.room_no <> booked.room_no
order by 1
```

This works. It is a little complicated but basically first checks all the rooms that are booked and then does a comparison between rooms not booked on each day of the month till the next 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is separate problem into 2 parts (in the end was 2 queries joined together). May not be the most efficient but the solution is correct.

1) Of the single rooms, look at the last check-out date, and see which one is vacant first (i.e. no more bookings for the rest of the month)
2) check in between current reservations - and see if there's a 3 day gap between them
3) join those together - grab the min

```
WITH subquery AS( -- existing single-bed bookings in Dec 
SELECT room_no, booking_date, 
        DATE_ADD(booking_date, INTERVAL (nights-1) DAY) AS last_night
   FROM booking
   WHERE room_type_requested='single' AND
         DATE_ADD(booking_date, INTERVAL (nights-1) DAY)>='2016-12-1' AND 
         booking_date <='2016-12-31'
   ORDER BY room_no, last_night) 

SELECT room_no, MIN(first_avail) AS first_avail --3) join the 2 together
FROM( 

-- 1) check the last date the room is booked in December (available after)

SELECT room_no, MIN(first_avail) AS first_avail
  FROM(
      SELECT room_no, DATE_ADD(MAX(last_night), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS first_avail
        FROM subquery q3
        GROUP BY 1
        ORDER BY 2) AS t2

UNION 

-- 2) check if any 3-day exist in between reservations 

SELECT room_no, DATE_ADD(MIN(end2), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS first_avail
  FROM(
      SELECT q1.booking_date AS beg1, q1.room_no, q1.last_night AS end1, 
             q2.booking_date AS beg2, q2.last_night AS end2
        FROM subquery q1
        JOIN subquery q2 
          ON q1.room_no = q2.room_no AND q2.booking_date > q1.last_night
      GROUP BY 2,1
      ORDER BY 2,1) AS t
      WHERE beg2-end1 > 3) AS inner_t
```

Answer (score 0):

This works conceptually as the first avaiable date should always be the end of the previous booking.

```
SELECT MIN(DATE_ADD(a.booking_date, INTERVAL nights DAY)) AS i
FROM booking AS a
WHERE DATE_ADD(a.booking_date, INTERVAL nights DAY)
      >= '2016-12-01'
      AND room_type_requested = 'single'
      AND NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT 1 FROM booking AS b
        WHERE b.booking_date BETWEEN
        DATE_ADD(a.booking_date, INTERVAL nights DAY) 
        AND DATE_ADD(a.booking_date, INTERVAL nights+2 DAY)
        AND a.room_no = b.room_no)
```